# Set tag id as an object attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
buttons = buttons.map(function(assetf,index){
          return(
            assetf.map(function(asset, index){
              return(
                <select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" id=asset._id>
             )
            }
          )
         }
```

So basicly I want to set the id of the select tag to the _id variable in the passed asset object. How can I do this?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly brackets.

```
<select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" id={asset._id}>
```